# Error while plotting circles using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to draw a (semi-transparent) circle on top of an array of randomly generated points (between `[0,1]` ) using python. I want the circle to be centered at `(0.5, 0.5)`

This is the code that I have written:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x_gal = np.random.rand(20)
y_gal = np.random.rand(20)

x_rand = np.random.rand(5*20) 
y_rand = np.random.rand(5*20)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot( x_gal, y_gal, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
plt.plot( 0.5, 0.5, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
plt.plot( x_rand, y_rand, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='b' )
plt.axis('off')

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r', alpha=0.5)
plt.add_artist(circle1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Without the lines in the code which refer to `circle1`, I get normal output (without the desired circle). But when I include the lines in the code which refer to `circle1`, I get the following error output.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_artist'
```

What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add artist on an axis, not on the module alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use add_artist from axes, the following is the quickest way to get the current axes using `plt.gcf`, get current figure, and `get_gca`, get current axes, also I recommend `plt.axis('equal')` to draw a circle vs oval:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl

x_gal = np.random.rand(20)
y_gal = np.random.rand(20)

x_rand = np.random.rand(5*20) 
y_rand = np.random.rand(5*20)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot( x_gal, y_gal, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
plt.plot( 0.5, 0.5, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
plt.plot( x_rand, y_rand, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='b' )
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis('equal')

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r', alpha=0.5)
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Scott: Many thanks for the very helpful answer. It worked. =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to plot on axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x_gal = np.random.rand(20)
y_gal = np.random.rand(20)

x_rand = np.random.rand(5*20) 
y_rand = np.random.rand(5*20)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot( x_gal, y_gal, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
ax.plot( 0.5, 0.5, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='r' )
ax.plot( x_rand, y_rand, ls=' ', marker='o', markersize=5, color='b' )
ax.axis('off')

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(circle1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]